# To Migrate AWS Services from one AWS Account to another AWS Account

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have setup one project in AWS Cloud Service. There I was using EC2 Instance, AMI, Elastic IP, Internet Gate Way, NACL, Route Table, Security Group, custom VPC, Private and Public Sub net, Elastic Load Balance, Auto scaling, Launch Configuration, KMS-key, Lambda, RDS Aurora Instance, S3 Bucket, Simple Email Service, Simple Queue Service, Simple Notification Service, Cloud watch logs. Now My client asking to migrate all services from existing AWS account to New AWS Account.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Just contact AWS support. If you are doing a migration not a copy, then the account can be changed with no interruption of service directly by AWS. Open a case in the AWS support center. See [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/transfer-aws-account/)

If you need a copy of those services into a different account, is a more complicated task as your will have to create different physical resources. For that I would recommend using CloudFormation.

Comment: Many Thanks Elzo Valugi. already open a case for this process. I want to know that Is possible to copy all services from existing to new account?

Comment: CloudFormation. Is solved all my task? I didn't use CloudFormation. I have to look at this

Comment: With CloudFormation you can build a template of your complete environment and replicate that into another account.

Comment: @LakshminarayananS did you find useful steps? I want to do the same. Give some advice if possible.

Comment: i can't believe they suggest to change the name/email/password and transfer it in this way? I got Wise.com account banned for trying to do it, I don't want to risk AWS